# Most numbers on back worn by a Player

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics

In almost all sports, Players wore jersey with numbers on back. It's helpful for the commentators, scorekeepers, statisticians, umpires and fans to know about exact player. Some of the Players believe in number game and keep on changing numbers, to change their luck(funny, but real). And some wore to respect their achievements(For ex. Gayle wore jersey with 333,his highest in tests ).

I want to know which Player wore/change numbers on back maximum times?

Comment: I am not getting this questions : I want to know which Player wore/change numbers on back maximum times? and the title Most numbers on back worn by a player. Please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other but i know about these two players

**SOURAV GANGULY :-**

Sourav ganguly is superstitious and believe in astrology. Ganguly had changed Jersey numbers time to time according to the astrology. Sourav ganguly had played `1999 world cup wearing Jersey with number 1.`

`He had decided on 99` after he was made skipper and an astrologer suggested that the number would bring good luck to his side. And later turned to `Jersey number 24`.

**SACHIN TENDULKAR :-**

Sachin used to wear `Jersey number 99`.
The biggest no. One can have on Jersey.`But later he turned up to number 10` 
as his mother told him number 10 would be lucky for him according to the astrologer, and he put number 10 on his jersey.

> Mumbai Indians has decided to retire the Jersey number 10 after sachin's
>   retirement.

**VIRENDER SEHWAG:-**

Used to wear `number 44`. But today, he is the only cricketer in the world who `wears no number`. Apparently, he did that on Jumani's behest. Says a source, Number 8 was proving to be unlucky, so he visited Jumaani, who suggested he do away with the number 8.

Comment: My question was to know about ,the most numbers on back worn by a Player. Your answer doesn't provide that.

Comment: then you should change question `I want to know which Player wore/change numbers on back maximum times?'